# How does the chrome cache work with auto updating extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

We are developing a chrome extension that has auto-updating capability.

When the extension is updated automatically, does it force a refresh on the cache for the files in that extension. I.e. what does a user have to do to actually see the changes in the new extension. Is it required that they do a hard refresh to guarantee that they see the latest version of the extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never had any problems with updating, I would say it clears the cache.

Never seen any extension asking you to refresh something or re-enable itself either.

Comment: Agree with this, with the exception of if the extension asks for more permissions it'll prompt you to authorize those new permissions, and disable it if you decline. If you're not changing the permissions requests, you should be okay.